# How to Group by ID and sort by datetimestamp and create a table with a new row with old and new value in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to do the following in pandas

I have three columns, an ID, datetime and Value.

```
ID,          DATE_TIME,VALUE

FLT09045412, 2019-01-02 12:03:23, 6

FLT09045412, 2019-01-30 14:38:47, 7
```

I want to create a new table out of this like

```
ID,            DATE_TIME,             OLD_VALUE,   NEW_VALUE  

FLT09045412,   2019-01-02 12:03:23,   NAN,         6

FLT09045412,   2019-01-30 14:38:47,   6,           7
```

each comma represents a new column

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

IIUC,

```
df['NEW_VALUE'] = df['VALUE']
df = df.sort_values('DATE_TIME')

df['OLD_VALUE'] = df.groupby('ID')['VALUE'].shift()
```

Output:

```
            ID            DATE_TIME  VALUE  NEW_VALUE  OLD_VALUE
0  FLT09045412  2019-01-02 12:03:23      6          6        NaN
1  FLT09045412  2019-01-30 14:38:47      7          7        6.0
```